# Prevent dropdown from collapsing when hover over element

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, submenu

The question isn't very clear, because I don't know how to ask it properly.

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyd3a/1/).

When you hover over About us, a dropdown menu is shown with a little green pointer. When your mouse goes over that pointer, the menu collapses.

I would like to know, is it possible to prevent that pointer from collapsing the menu.

I've tried putting the div with the pointer in the `<li>` tag, but then the jQuery gets tricky.

Is there anything else I can try that might work?

Comment: Can you add the arrow as a child element to the <li> on hover? then remove it on mouseout? I don't see your code for the actual adding of the dropdown or I would attempt it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would solve it using borders for the pointer, and place it with a psuedo-class of the hovered element.

This will work in IE7 and above.

```
.menu > ul > li:hover > a:before {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-top-color: #445921;
    border-width: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
    z-index:9;
}
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mx877/

Comment: If I could up vote this twice, I'd do it. Fantastic answer as it works PERFECTLY.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer is not in the `.menu > ul > li` element which you are trying to select with the hover function:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.menu > ul > li').hover(function(e) {
```

You could:

1. Replace the .pointer div with a background image in your `.menu > ul > li`.
2. You could move the .pointer div into the corresponding `.menu > ul > li` element:

   ```
   $('.pointer').appendTo($(this));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the cursor is actually losing focus from the menu when you hover the little rotated square. Expand the padding on the top level element to include the square and it works fine.

```
        <li style="padding-bottom:10px;"><a href="index.html">ABOUT US</a>
            <ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Vyd3a/3/